# 1.9.1 Swatch Icons - Display out-of-stock options

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.1.0

Using the new 1.9.1, my products have these sizes: S, M, L.

If say, M is out of stock, how can I display the M option but crossed out?

(1.9.1 seems to have the functionality built-in for when you have two options and the combination is out of stock).

Comment: :)

i use this link. Hope it will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798049/show-out-of-stock-simple-products-in-the-configurable-product

Comment: Thank you. It is almost perfect except it takes about 5 seconds for the option to change from an in-stock colour to the crossed-out of-of-stock colour. The browser just says 'Connecting .....'. Any ideas?